# Javascript AJAX - Send Image File Input and Text Input To PHP file to insert to SQL database

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

I have a form which allows the user to enter details about a photograph and also upload the image. I need all off the inputs to be obtained by a Javascript file and then sent to a PHP file where the data is stored in a database and the image is stored in a file. I'm really not too sure about how to go about this.

Below is my HTML form:

```
            <form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">

                <div id="upload-header">
                    <h2>Upload Photo</h2>

                    <svg class="close-icon" width="12px" height="12px" viewPort="0 0 12 12" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <line x1="1" y1="11" x2="11" y2="1" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
                        <line x1="1" y1="1" x2="11" y2="11" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
                    </svg>
                </div>

                <div class="divider"></div>
                <p>Upload a new photograph to the system.</p>

                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <input type="text" id="photoname" class="field-style" name="PhotoName" placeholder="Photograph name"/>
                </div>

                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <input type="text" id="photodesc" class="field-style" name="PhotoDesc" placeholder="Photograph description"/>
                </div>

                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <label for="dob">Date taken</label>
                    <input type="date" id="photodate" class="field-style" name="photodate"/>
                </div>

                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <input type="text" id="photostreet" class="field-style" name="photostreet" placeholder="Street"/>
                </div>

                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <input type="text" id="photocity" class="field-style" name="photocity" placeholder="City"/>
                </div>

                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <input type="text" id="photocountry" class="field-style" name="photocountry" placeholder="Country"/>
                </div>

                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <input type="text" id="photopc" class="field-style" name="photopc" placeholder="Postcode"/>
                </div>

                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <input type="radio" id="public" class="field-style" name="display" value="Public" checked/>
                    <label for="public">Public</label>
                </div>

                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <input type="radio" id="private" class="field-style" name="display" value="Private"/>
                    <label for="public">Private</label>
                </div>

                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <input type="file" id="photofile" class="field-style" name="photofile" accept=".jpg"/>
                </div>

                <div id="upload_error"></div>

                <button class="button upload-button" type="button"id="upload-button" name="upPhoto"/>Upload</button>

            </form>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
            $("#upload-button").click(function() {

    var name = $('#photoname').val();
    var desc = $('#photodesc').val();
    var date = new Date($('#photodate').val());
    day = '' + date.getDate();
    month = '' + (date.getMonth() + 1);
    year = date.getFullYear();
    if (month.length < 2) {
        month = '0' + month;
    }
    if (day.length < 2) {
        day = '0' + day;
    }
    var date = [year, month, day].join('-');
    var street = $('#photostreet').val();
    var city = $('#photocity').val();
    var country = $('#photocountry').val();
    var pc = $('#photopc').val();
    var pubpri = $('input[name=display]:checked').val();

    $('#photofile').change(function(e) {
        var file = this.files[0];
        var form = new FormData();
        form.append('name', name);
        form.append('desc', desc);
        form.append('date', date);
        form.append('street', street);
        form.append('city', city);
        form.append('country', country);
        form.append('pc', pc);
        form.append('pubpri', pubpri);
        form.append('photofile', file)

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "upload.php",
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form,
            success: function(response) {
                $('#upload-error').html(response);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Here is what I created for my PHP file just to test the starting variables:

```
<?php

session_start();

// Load DB config and connect to the database
include 'db.php';
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db);

// Get variables
$name = $_POST['name'];
$desc = $_POST['desc'];

echo "$name $desc";
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'd like to know how I can get what the user has inputted in the form and then sent to the PHP file with the ajax request. Currently, i'm getting no response back from the echo in the PHP file and no errors either.